# Angular App inside Wordpress Page

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress

we have a simple Angular 1 App we would like to implement inside a wordpress page.
i tried adding it as a plugin, but it doesn't seem to work.
this is (sort of) the script:

```
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="Wallf as vm">
        <div id="newLeadView"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://test.com/Components/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://test.com/Components/scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://test.com/Components/scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://test.com/Components/app.js"></script>
<script src="https://test.com/Components/services/generalService.js"></script>
<script src="https://test.com/Components/controllers/Wallf.js"></script>

<link href="https://test.com/Components/content/general.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>
    var sId = "345";
    var Name = "e92";
    var template = "2";
</script>
```

it however doesn't work and errors-out.
any help would be very appreciated...

**EDIT:**
i've loaded the modules via wordpress functions.php.
now i get this unclear error:
Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
{1}

how can i troubleshoot this?

Comment: Please check this links maybe useful for you https://www.kevinleary.net/angularjs-wordpress-tutorial/

Comment: Your first step is to learn how to enqueue scripts the [WordPress Way](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/).  And, don't load jQuery or jQuery ui from your plugin, but instead use the WP built-in scripts.

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: Mixing jQuery UI with AngularJS is asking for problems. If you use jQuery, it should be loaded before AngularJS.

Comment: Hi @georgeawg, this is an old code that worked for us in a SharePoint implementation, and now we want to move it to our new WordPress infrastructure. 
As far as I can tell, it just doesn't recognize the angular functions. Doesn't load the source.